# Alterar valor de uma variável com botão PHP

Tags: php

Quero alterar o valor desta variável.

```
$beg_j = $numjour;
```

Para isto,

```
$beg_j = $numjour-1;
```

botão:

```
echo "<input type=button value=Change onclick=$beg_j-1>";
```

Comment: Parece que está procurando por AJAX. Mas acho que precisa explicar qual problema está tentando resolver não só o código que não funciona ou que deseja que funcione.

Answer (score 1):

Isto não é possível. O php roda no servidor e depois de executado, fica tudo por conta do cliente (browser).

Quando o browser faz uma solicitação ao servidor, o php é executado e retorna o resultado (html) para o browser. Esse é o seu ciclo de vida. Ele não permanece em execução como é o caso do javascript.

Se você quer executar um script php quando o usuário clicar em um botão, sem recarregar a página, então você deve estudar sobre AJAX.

Answer (score -1):

O certo seria você colocar algo mais completo do que já fez e está tentando fazer, mas vou tentar passar uma ideia para que possa tentar implementar, desta forma não precisará recarregar a página para decrementar ou alterar o valor da sua variável, qualquer coisa poste aqui suas dificuldades.

Use ajax para enviar o valor para uma página php onde existirá uma variável que receberá esse valor e alterará o valor dela conforme a sua necessidade, exemplo: no seu javascript contido em sua página principal faça:

```
var url = "seuArquivo.php";
var data = "numjour="+valor;//Na variável "valor" vc pode atribuir um valor específico vindo do seu form por exemplo.
$.ajax({                 
        type: 'POST',                 
        //dataType: 'json',                 
        url: url,                 
        async: true,                 
        data: data,                 
        success: function(response) {
            $("#idSuaDiv").val(response);
            //Isso colocaria o resultado em sua div, mas vc pode fazer outras coisas aqui com a resposta
        }             
    });
```

No seu arquivo .php precisaria apenas pegar o valor e fazer algo com ela ou processar da maneira que bem entender, exemplo:

```
 $beg_j = $_POST["numjour"];
    //agora faça o que vc quiser com a variável e depois mande a resposta de volta pro form.
print_r($beg_j);
```